# How to handle lists for eks assume policy

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I have 2 eks cluster as part of our upgrade. I want to handle assume policy such that it has access to both eks cluster. Both the cluster in same AWS account.

i want my policy to look like the below policy. such that the we are not updating any roles, but only the assume policy to handle both clusters.

locals.tf

```
  eks_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::11111111111:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
        "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::11111111111:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:sub": "system:serviceaccount:%s:%s",
          "oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/xxxxxxxxxxxxx:sub": "system:serviceaccount:%s:%s"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
EOF
```

Launcher = "job-Launcher"

Role.tf

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "launcher" {
  name               = local.Launcher
  assume_role_policy = format(local.eks_policy, "my-namepsace", local.Launcher)
  tags = {
    terraform = "true"
    owner     = "stg"
  }
}
```

So i tried like this in locals.tf

```
  count = length(var.federated)

      eks_policy = <<EOF
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::11111111111:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/${join(",",${element(var.federated, count.index)})}",
          },
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
          "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
              "oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/${join(",", ${element(var.federated, count.index)})}:sub": "system:serviceaccount:%s:%s"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

But i'm getting an error as count cannot be used within locals.tf,
Can someone pls help me.

**Update2:**

How do we get something like this

```
"Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/xxxxxxxxxxxxx:sub": "system:serviceaccount:ihr-system:ihr-system-external-dns18",
          "oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/yyyyyyyyyyyyy:sub": "system:serviceaccount:ihr-system:ihr-system-external-dns"
        }
      }
```

I tried this ,

federated = [
"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
]

```
    Condition : {
      "StringEquals" : {
        join("",[for oidc in local.federated:"oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/${oidc}:sub:","system:serviceaccount:%s:%s"])
    }
```

> getting syntax error near in , local expected and another error got
> ',' or '}' expected got '"system:serviceaccount.."'

```
for oidc in local.federated
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform [format](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/format.html#specification-syntax) function expects an argument per each placeholder. From the documentation:

> The specification is a string that includes formatting verbs that are introduced with the % character. The function call must then have one additional argument for each verb sequence in the specification. The verbs are matched with consecutive arguments and formatted as directed, as long as each given argument is convertible to the type required by the format verb.

With that said, you need to provide four arguments, even though it's the same local variables in your case:

```
format(local.eks_policy, "my-namepsace", local.Launcher, "my-namepsace", local.Launcher)
```

Depending on your use case, you might also consider defining a list of objects with configuration and build the policy statement using loop in order to prepare final string.

**Update 1**

Example with dynamic generation might look like this, where role could be assumed by any account from the variable `local.params`:

```
locals {
  # key = account ID, value could be whatever
  params = {
    "1111" = { foo = "bar" },
    "2222" = { x = "y" }
  }

  assume_role_str = jsonencode({
    # skipped beginning for brevity
    Effect = "Allow",
    Principal = {
      Federated: [ for account in keys(local.params): "arn:aws:iam::11111111111:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/:${account}" ]
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: How can i make more dynamic , there are couple of roles, so we would want to avoid the making update to the roles, instead how can i make it dynamic that it takes both eks id in assume policy

Comment: @user6826691 I updated the answer and added an example of dynamic generation